# How Do I Get Customer Custom Attribute Value

Tags: php, magento

When I run the following two lines of code, I get returned the value 161. Now if I dig through `customer_eav`, I see 161 relates to `attribute_id` 477, and then if I dig further into `customer_entity_varchar` I find a row with `field['attribute_id']=477` and the value is USD. How can I get this attribute string value using magento's models / methods...

```
$customer = $session->getCustomer();
$attributes = $customer->getDefaultCurrency(); // returns 161... not USD
```

Comment: you can create customer attributes, they populate the customer eav table... you can get the customer attribute using the magic methog getAttributeName(), but it returns a foreign id code...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
echo $customer->getResource()
              ->getAttribute('default_currency')
              ->getFrontend()
              ->getValue($customer);
```

Comment: actually wow that worked. thanks a million. I tried that earlier and it failed, i must have had a syntax mistake or been calling a funky method.

Comment: It's a funky syntax due to the rather large object population involved.